# Horizontally and vertically centring DIVs into 100% height and width parent DIVs

Tags: css, html

I have stacked parent DIVs that are height and width 100% of the browser window and cannot seem to get secondary DIVs to centre inside of their respective divs.

Here are my stacked parents:

```
#parent1 {
    min-height:100%;
    height: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#parent2 {
    min-height:100%;
    height: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I want to set it up so my content floats centred within these stacked DIVs:

```
<div id="parent1">    <-- fits entire browser window --/
   <div id="content1"></div>  <-- centred horz. and vert. in parent1 --/
</div>
<div id="parent2">    <-- fits entire browser window but under parent1 --/
   <div id="content2"></div>  <-- centred horz. and vert. in parent2 --/
</div>
```

...And so on.
As it stands my content CSS looks like this, but it's not working:

```
#content1 {
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;
    left:50%;
    right:50%;
    margin:-250px 0 0 -500px;
}
```

I've had no luck with absolute or relative positioning, either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add position property as follows:

```
#parent1 {
    min-height:100%;
    height: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#parent2 {
    min-height:100%;
    height: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#content1 {
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;
    left:50%;
    right:50%;
    margin:-250px 0 0 -500px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kalpesh, in trying to use positioning I had mixed up which to use where.

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent1 {
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#CCFF00;


}

#parent2 {
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#66CCFF;


}
#content1 {
    width:500px;
    background-color:#9900CC;
    height:500px;
    margin:350px;
    float:left;

}
```

colors are given to knw the exact position..
try to use `float:left` in child div

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you wanna horizontally center align. the content div or the parent div.
just give them this class

```
.middle{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```